# How to make Django admin honor grammatical cases in languages like Polish?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin

Django allows overwriting `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` of a `Model`, which allows us to specify correct plural forms of `Model` names for non-English languages (for example `Kandydaci` as a plural of `Kandydat` instead of the default `Kandydats` which looks weird in Polish).

However, this is far from enough for languages with grammatical cases. For example, Django Admin gleefully displays us something like that:

[image]

(Where `Zaznacz kandydat do zmiany` stands for `Select kandydat to change` - `Kandydat` is a name of a `Model`)

This is incorrect. In this sentence the model name should have been displayed in [accusative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case), which is `kandydata`. However, I cannot simply specify that `verbose_name` of this `Model` is `Kandydata`, since would also affect all places where [nominative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_case) is expected instead - I've found one such place so far, and this is the heading of the table column:

[image]

This is incorrenct since the table heading should be called `Kandydat` not `Kandydata`.

How to fix this?

Comment: Note:Only one language is required for the app, and that is Polish.

Comment: Did the below answer helped you with your question?

Comment: @nik_m I'll check it out soon, as of now I had to shift to a different part of the project, and have to leave the admin stuff for a little later. But in a few days I'll be back to admin for sure and then I'll check Your answer, for which I'm really grateful. Sorry for the delay but I just have to .

Comment: yes no problem! My apologies for being rush on this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'Select <verbose_name> to change'` is declared inside the [admin's main view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L83)

> `self.title = title % force_text(self.opts.verbose_name)`

as a [`{{ title }}`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L73) template variable

> `{% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}`

So, touching the built-in view is out of question. But there is another way of doing it! You see, Django Admin templates are full of [`{% block %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)s acting as placeholders in order to override them. Read more at the official docs about [overriding Admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

So, to your question.

1. Under your project's root directory create a directory `templates` (if it doesn't exists already).
2. Under `my_project/templates/` create another one, `admin`.
3. Under `my_project/templates/admin/` create a file `change_list.html`.
4. Inside `my_project/templates/admin/change_list.html` put these:

   ```
   {% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}

   {% load myutils_filters %}

   {% comment %}
   You have to create an app that will hold all common tags/filters
   that are re-usable across your entire project.
   The model class itself is passed as cl.model
   {% endcomment %}

   {% block content_title %}{{ block.super|to_accusative:cl.model }}{% endblock %}
   ```
5. Inside your `myutils/templatetags/myutils_filters.py` file put these:

   ```
   from django import template
   from django.utils.html import format_html
   from django.utils.encoding import force_text

   register = template.Library()

   @register.filter()
   def to_accusative(value, model):
       verbose_name = model._meta.verbose_name  # declared in Meta
       new_name = force_text(model.accusative case())  # a custom class method (lives in your Model)
       return format_html(value.replace(verbose_name, new_name))
   ```
6. Finally, under your app's `models.py`, under each model `class` define a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#classmethod) method like this:

   ```
   from django.db import models
   from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

   class MyModel(models.Model):
       # model fields here

       def __str__():
           return self.a_field

       class Meta:
           verbose_name = 'verbose name'
           verbose_name_plural = 'verbose name plural'
           # accusative_case = 'accusative name case' # BAD. Raises error. Implement a class method intead ;)

       @classmethod
       def accusative_case(cls):
           # You'll define the Polish translation as soon as you run makemessages
           return _('Name in english of the accusative case')
   ```
7. Run `manage.py makemessages`, `manage.py compilemessages`, reload your browser and voila!

Note: The above may look a little *hackish* but it works brilliant. Tested locally and works.